# How to get zoomed image bitmap in android?

Tags: android

```
public class ImageZoomActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageViewTouch  mImageView;
    int width,height;
    Bitmap snoop;
int i=1,k=1;
     Matrix mat ;

static   Bitmap resizedBitmap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        setContentView( R.layout.editface );
         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String   str = bundle.getString("image");
          File imgfile=new File(str);
          snoop=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgfile.getAbsolutePath());

     getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
               mat = new Matrix();
                 mat.postRotate(0);
         resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(snoop, 0, 0,
                 snoop.getWidth(), snoop.getHeight(), mat, true);
        mImageView.setImageBitmapReset( snoop, 0, true );

        ImageView leftarrow=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.leftarrow);
        leftarrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                 mat = new Matrix();
                 mat.postRotate(360-k*1);
                 resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(snoop, 0, 0,
                         snoop.getWidth(), snoop.getHeight(), mat, true);
                 mImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                 i--;
                 k++;
                            }
        });
        ImageView   rigtharrow=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rigtharrow);
        rigtharrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 mat = new Matrix();
                 mat.postRotate(1*i);
                 resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(snoop, 0, 0,
                         snoop.getWidth(), snoop.getHeight(), mat, true);
                 mImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                 i++;
                 k--;
      }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged()
    {
        super.onContentChanged();
        mImageView = (ImageViewTouch)findViewById( R.id.imageView1 );
    }
      @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
             inflater.inflate(R.menu.next, menu);
             return true;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
             // Handle item selection
             switch (item.getItemId()) {

             case R.id.next:

                Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createBitmap(resizedBitmap, 45, 20,240,310, mat, true);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bt.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            Intent i = new Intent(ImageZoomActivity.this,AdjustGoggles.class);
            i.putExtra("btmap", bt);
            i.putExtra("image", byteArray);
              startActivity(i);

                 return true;

             default:

                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
             }

     }


}
```

using these code i am getting zooming and rotating image how can i get zoomed image bitmap.I want to use zoomed image in next activity.Rotating image is returning resizedBitmap.what i want to do for getting ResultentBitmap for zoomed image.

Comment: beside the hard to understand question (`I am getting zooming` vs `how can I get zoomed`) your code is really messy because there is no formatting. Please take the time to improve your question

Comment: You should explain what problem you are getting.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280413/2399238

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to retrieve a zoomed bitmap from original bitmap with same resolution as original bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getZoomedImage(Bitmap originalImage, float scale) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)(originalImage.getWidth()*scale), (int)(originalImage.getHeight()*scale), false);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(
            scaledBitmap,
            (scaledBitmap.getWidth()-originalImage.getWidth())/2,
            (scaledBitmap.getHeight()-originalImage.getHeight())/2,
            originalImage.getWidth(),
            originalImage.getHeight());
}
```